# Aggregate test using python's unit-test is running without test runner

Tags: python, unit-testing, selenium, webdriver

I am having a problem in running an aggregated test suite of selenium tests using unit-test in python.

Below code is executing the test from another module without the testRunner being called.

When I tried executing in debug mode, the control was passed to pydev_runfiles soon after it executed the class definition line and eventually executed the test in the other module(gmailbutton).

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
from gmailbutton import gmailButton

class runner():
    def runner1(self):
        suite = unittest.TestSuite()
        suite.addTest(gmailButton)
        return suite
```

As per the documentation(http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html) the above code had to just add the test case to the suite and test should have executed on

```
unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
```

which is not happening here.

Test code for gmailButton is here

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver


class gmailButton(unittest.TestCase):

    global browser

    def test_gmailButton(self):

        browser = webdriver.Firefox()

        try:
            browser.get("http://www.gmail.com")           
            browser.find_element_by_id("Email").send_keys("abcd")
            browser.find_element_by_id("Passwd").send_keys("123445")
            browser.find_element_by_id("signIn").click()

        except Exception as e:
            raise
            print e

        finally:
            browser.close()
```

UPDATE:

Here is the exact code I am executing from eclipse.

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
from gmailbutton import gmailButton
from pyUnitExercise import exercise1

class runner():
    def runner1(self):
        suite = unittest.TestSuite()
        suite.addTest(gmailButton)
        return suite

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(runner.suite)
```

My expectation from this code is to execute gmailButton test case and NOT exercise1 which is just imported and not added to the test suite. I've no idea why is it executing the test which was just imported and not added to the test suite.

Comment: What's happening when you run it? Do you get any errors or messages?

Comment: I don't get any errors. Instead, gmailButton script gets executed. I am trying to understand why is this happening.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following. Is it executing without you calling `unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)`? I can't reproduce the problem with the above code.

Comment: Yes. That's right. It is executing without calling     unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite) Please note that gmailbutton.py is a different module which I am importing in another module.

Comment: Is there anything else in `gmailbutton.py`? Perhaps it's running on import? If so, you should use `if __name__ == "__main__": main()`

Comment: There is nothing else in gmailButton.py. Yes, it is running on import.  I've included if __name__ == "__main__": main(). Now, I've imported another module without adding it to the testsuite. I want only the test included in the suite to run and not everything I've imported, which is not happening with this change.

Comment: Can you please update your question with the exact command line that you're running that causes the issue?

Comment: @WickedGrey - Have updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using PyDev, you are probably not actually using python's stdlib unittest.  It uses nose and/or py.test:

http://pydev.org/manual_adv_pyunit.html

Both of those libraries search for tests via introspection; you don't need to add explicit entries to a test suite.  Without the output from when the tests get run, it's hard to tell if this is actually what's going on, though.

Answer (score 0):

I use [nose](https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) in preference to unit-test, but here's one way that seems to work for me:

```
>>> import unittest
>>> class gmailButton(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_gmailButton(self):
        pass


>>> suite = unittest.TestSuite()
>>> loader = unittest.TestLoader()
>>> tests = loader.loadTestsFromTestCase(gmailButton)
>>> suite.addTest(tests)
>>> unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
test_gmailButton (__main__.gmailButton) ... ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.047s

OK
<unittest.runner.TextTestResult run=1 errors=0 failures=0>
```

Comment: The problem I am facing is, the gmailButton test is getting loaded even before reaching     unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)